Problem using PowerShell Expression statement
I'm trying to run the below PowerShell code to get information about accounts that have a specific Company Name in Azure AD.  The below code works, except for the Expression statement to get the Manager. ID is an object, and apparently it needs to be converted to a string for use with get-mgusermanager.  I'm guessing there should be some way to do -userid $($_.Id | Out-String) or something, but that doesn't work.
get-mgbetauser -all -filter "CompanyName eq 'Global Office'" -ConsistencyLevel eventual -count test | select-object -Property DisplayName,Mail,JobTitle,Country,Id,@{Name='manager';Expression={(get-mgusermanager -userid $_.Id -property userprincipalname).userprincipalname}}

Need to convert $_.Id to a string within the confines of the Expression statement.

Not sure how you can do it with Get-MgBetaUser I personally don't use it but with Invoke-MgGraphRequest you can make a direct API call to the List users endpoint and use the $expand parameter to get both details in a single call.
This is how the code would look:
$uri = "v1.0/users?`$filter=companyName eq 'Global Office'&`$expand=manager"

$result = do {
    $response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET $uri
    $uri = $response.'@odata.nextLink'

    foreach ($user in $response.value) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            DisplayName = $user['displayName']
            Mail        = $user['mail']
            JobTitle    = $user['jobTitle']
            Country     = $user['country']
            Id          = $user['id']
            Manager     = $user['manager']['userPrincipalName']
        }
    }
}
while ($uri)

# do stuff with result...
$result

